# How to zip folders in Ipad

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios7, zip, xcode5

In my Application,I am taking screenshots of image View and then I am saving those screen shots in document folder of the application.Now I want to Email all those images with the same folder structure they are in.Zipping all the folders containing the images?

```
-(void)ZipFile2{
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
BOOL isDir=NO;
NSArray *subpaths;
NSString *exportPath = docDirectory;
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:exportPath isDirectory:&isDir] && isDir){
    subpaths = [fileManager subpathsAtPath:exportPath];
}
NSString *archivePath = [docDirectory stringByAppendingString:@"Uploads.zip"];    
ZipArchive *archiver = [[ZipArchive alloc] init];
[archiver CreateZipFile2:archivePath];
for(NSString *path in subpaths)
{
    NSString *longPath = [exportPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:path];
    if([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:longPath isDirectory:&isDir] && !isDir)
    {
        [archiver addFileToZip:longPath newname:path];
    }
}
BOOL successCompressing = [archiver CloseZipFile2];
if(successCompressing)
    NSLog(@"Success");
else
    NSLog(@"Fail");
```

}

I use this code but the zip file is not created in my Ipad ??? can you Help Me

Answer (score 0):

ZipArchive has a delegate protocol which sends a message whenever a error occurs.

add below ZipArchive allocation.

```
archiver.delegate = self
```

Add protocol to header class and then implement the following method:

```
- (void)ErrorMessage:(NSString*) msg {
    NSLog(@"Zip error: %@", msg);
}
```